# How to output elements of an ArrayList based on the frequency?

Tags: arraylist, collections

My Arraylist looks like [A, B, D, E, C, A, A, B]

and i want to print to console

```
A,3
B,2
C,1
D,1
E,1
```

How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of your array are of type char this can be a approached using another array

```java
char[] foo = new char['Z' - 'A'];
```

then you will loop through your original array incrementing the position of that char in foo. if you use a fast sorting algorithm afterwards afterwards you can just print them out but if `i+1 = i` then compare them by char value

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class MyClass {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        printListElementFrequencies(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "D", "E", "C", "A", "A", "B"));
    }
    
    static void printListElementFrequencies(List<String> list) {
        Map<String, Long> frequencies = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
        Comparator<String> sortByFrequencyThenLexicographically = Comparator.<String, Long>comparing(frequencies::get).reversed().thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(s -> s));
        list.stream().sorted(sortByFrequencyThenLexicographically).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + ", " + frequencies.get(s)));
    }
    
}
```

Edit: I missed the sorting part.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hashmap, in which there will be one entry per symbol. The symbol itself will be the 'key' and the # of times that symbol shows up will be the value within the hashmap.

Iterate through your list, each time you find a new symbol, add a matching entry to the map, and each time you find an existing symbol, add one to its value in the hashmap

Add the hashmaps' entryset to a list, sort that list using a comparator then print this sorted list out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mySymbols = "A,B,D,E,C,A,A,B";
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(myList, mySymbols.split(","));
    HashMap<String, Integer> countingMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String s : myList){
        if(countingMap.containsKey(s)){
            Integer newValue = countingMap.get(s) + 1;
            countingMap.put(s, newValue);
        }
        else{
            countingMap.put(s, 1);
        }
    }
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    entries.addAll(countingMap.entrySet());
    entries.sort(new Comparator<Entry>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
            return (Integer)o2.getValue() - (Integer)o1.getValue();
        }
    });
    Iterator iter = entries.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Entry thisEntry = (Entry) iter.next();
        Object key = thisEntry.getKey();
        Object value = thisEntry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key+", "+value);
    }

}
```

[Test the code here](http://jdoodle.com/ia/hJX)

Comment: There is convenient [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to populate the map: `for (String s : mySymbols.split(",")) { countingMap.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);}`

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by converting the list into frequency map and sorting the entry set by values in descending order and then by key:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "D", "E", "C", "A", "A", "B", "Z", "D");

list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting())) // Map<String, Long>
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    ) // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>>
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ", " + e.getValue()));
```

Output:

```
A, 3
B, 2
D, 2
C, 1
E, 1
Z, 1
```

Also it is possible to use `Collectors::toMap` with a merge function (here the frequency is calculated as `Integer`):

```java
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1, Integer::sum)) // Map<String, Integer>
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    )
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue()));
```